# Kotlin text validation

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to `Kotlin`, not so new to `Java` and `Android` development. But willing and trying to make a switch. I've wrote a simple validator for `EditText`
and was wondering if there is a way to write it more compact with lambdas.

```
textMTU.addTextChangedListener(object : EditTextValidator(textMTU) {
    override fun validate(textView: EditText, text: String) {
        val textToInt = if (text.isEmpty()) 0  else text.toInt()
        if (textToInt < 1280 || textToInt > 1500) {
            textView.error = getString(R.string.errorTroubleshoot)
        }
        else {
            textView.error = null
            val input = if (textMTU.rawText.isEmpty()) defaultSize else textMTU.rawText.toInt()
            if (input in 1281..1499) {
                prefs.mtuSize = input
            }
        }
    }
```

`EditTextValidator` here is simply extended `TextWatcher` without `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make attention - your code twice convert and check value. Suppose it's not efficient. Another tiny problem - 1280 and 1500 values is not change prefs.mtuSize…

My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = MainActivity::class.simpleName.toString()

    private val defaultSize = 1500
    private var prefsMtuSize: Int = defaultSize

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textMTU = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textMTU)

        // Extension function
        textMTU.addTextChangedListener { text ->
            val textToInt = try { text.toInt() } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 0 }
            if (textToInt in 1280..1500) { // 1280 <= textToInt <= 1500
                textMTU.error = null
                prefsMtuSize = textToInt
            } else {
                textMTU.error = getString(R.string.errorTroubleshoot)
                prefsMtuSize = defaultSize
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "prefsMtuSize = $prefsMtuSize")
        }
    }
}

private fun EditText.addTextChangedListener(testFunction: (text: String) -> Unit) {
    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            testFunction(s.toString())
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }
    })
}
```

Comment: Looks cleaner, thanks for your time answering :)